# AngularJS provide success callback of a factory method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a simple factory that returns a promise after a async.-request.

```
getUpdates: function(){
    var q = $q.defer();
    $http.get(...)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        q.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        q.reject(status);
    });
    return q.promise;
}
```

In my controller I just call the getUpdates-method and receive the promise.

```
var updates = factory.getUpdates();
```

How can I provide a success/error functionality of the getUpdates method?

```
factory.getUpdates().success(function(promise){...}).error(function(err)...
```

What do I have to add to my getUpdates function?

Comment: success and error are only available on $http, since you are returning q promise use then, as explained in answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$http` service already return a promise, there is no need to use `$q.defer()` to create an another promise in this case. You could just write it like this:

```
getUpdates: function () {
  return $http.get(...);
}
```

This way the `success()` and `error()` methods will still be available.

Or if you really have a reason why you are using `$q.defer()`, please include it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You `then` function to handle the success and failure of the promise:

```
factory.getUpdates()
  .then(function(value) {
    // handle success
  }, function(reason) {
    // handle failure
  });
```

Comment: this is very nice. i guess that's what I was after :)

Answer (score 0):

```
factory.getUpdates().then(
  //onSucess
  function(response)
  {
    // ...  
  },
  //onError

  function()
  {
    // ...      
  }
);
```